# Can not paint an image in my JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

I'm having trouble painting an image in my GraphicsPanel (extension of JPanel). I tried loading from a file with the pathname, using getCodeBase(), getDocumentBase(), getResource(), and using BufferedImage. Is there any way to draw the image without having to make it an ImageIcon inside a JLabel?

```
package rpg;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
private WorldBuilder wb;
public int currentTileType = 0;//tile types. 0=bgtile, 1=object, 2=NPC
public String currentTileName = "";
public Image currentTile;

public GraphicsPanel() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 720, 528);
    g.drawImage(currentTile, 100, 100, this);//Nothing gets drawn here
}

public void getParameters(WorldBuilder wb) {
    this.wb = wb;
    this.currentTileType = wb.currentTileType;
    this.currentTileName = wb.currentTileName;
    /*
    try {
        currentTile = ImageIO.read(new File("SpriteSheet.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("failed");
    }
    */
    currentTile = new ImageIcon("SpriteSheet.png").getImage();
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}

Comment: Painting at `100x100` could be painting beyond the visible range of the component.  `ImageIcon(String)` expects that the `String` is a file reference, so it the image is an embedded resource, the image will not be found. Try using `ImageIO.read` instead, as it will at least throw an `IOException` when something goes wrong...

Comment: The component has dimensions 720x528. I use ImageIO.read before but that also didn't work. At the moment, I just put the image file in the same directory as the java file to test it as reading straight from the file reference should work this way.

Comment: First of all, you didn't provide enough information to make a "guess" about the component size. Second if the image file is in the same "package" as the class file (`rpg`) then the file path is wrong, from the context of the application, it would be more like `rpg/SpriteSheet.png`.  You could do `System.out.println(new File("SpriteSheet.png").exists());` to test it, it will most likely print `false`.  If the `SpriteSheet.png` is within the context of the application, then you should try using `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("SpriteSheet.png"))` instead.

Comment: Sorry about the component size, forgot to say that in my opening post. It did in fact say "false" so I guess the issue may be the path name? It still said false after adding "rpg/SpriteSheet.png". I'm not that knowledgeable about default pathnames. If I have my image in the same package as my java file what would I use. Also if i wanted my images to be in a separate folder, where should I put the folder and how would I reference the images?

Comment: It's possible that the sprite has not being copied to the same location of the classes or is being treated as an embedded resource.  How are you build your application?  Did you try something `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("SpriteSheet.png"))`?

Comment: I just tried that but it still didn't work. When I do this:

`System.out.println(new File("C:\\Users\\Nick\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\RPG\\src\\rpg\\SpriteSheet.png").exists());`

it returns true

but 

`System.out.println(new File("SpriteSheet.png").exists());`

returns false

Comment: Try using `getClass().getResource("/rpg/SpriteSheet.png")` and make sure you are calling `getParameters` so that that resources are actually loaded.

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work. This GraphicsPanel is implemented inside a JFrame called WorldBuilder that I run. the red rectange in the paint method shows up but the image does not. I suspect I still am not entering in the right pathname. The test if "/rpg/SpriteSheet.png" returned false still.

Comment: DON'T treat the resource as a `File`.  It will embedded into your application Jar and is no longer a `File`, but a resource.  Make sure that you are calling `getParameters` and actually loading the image.

Comment: What do you mean by not treat is as a file but a resource? Also I confirmed that the getParameters is being run.

Comment: A `File` is something that resides within the context of the OS's file system.  A resource is something else.  In this context, it is something that lives inside your application Jar (but generally describes anything that can be accessed from within the context of the applications class path).  You can't load resources like `File`, they require special treatment, so using `File#exists` will always return `false`

Comment: So when loading my image I should use `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("pathname")`?

Comment: Yes, assuming that the image is an embedded resource, and given the fact that you are using Netbeans and putting the image within the applications source, then Netbeans will bundle it as. FYI: When executed, unless you've set it otherwise, the program will be run from the context of the projects directory.  Do Not included `src` in any path reference, this will only break your code

Comment: So it starts from the source directory? Then I think the `"\\rpg\\SpriteSheet.png"` should work right?

Comment: It will like you a lot more if you used `/rpg/SpriteSheet.png` instead ;)

Comment: The file.exists part returned false (because it's a resource as you said?) but I say `currentTile = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/rpg/SpriteSheet.png"));` and it still does not paint

Comment: But, assuming that `getParameters` is being called and `ImageIO` is not throwing an `Exception`, then the image is being loaded.  The next issue is figuring out why it's not being painted. At this point I'd be making sure that the instance of `GraphicsPanel` that you think you are loading is the same one on the screen...

Comment: .........well. That's it haha. For some reason I created a new GraphicsPanel in my WorldBuilder class instead of using the one I had placed in the GuiBuilder. This is my first time using an IDE and GuiBuilder haha. Well I would like to thank you very much. Have a great day!

Comment: Now you have a few extra things to add to your checklist for trouble shooting ;)

Answer (score 1):

Summary of comments:

- The `SpriteSheet.png` is not located within location that `ImageIcon(String)` would be able to find it.  `ImageIcon(String)` expects that the `String` references a `File` on the file system, but `SpriteSheet.png` is stored within the application context (`src/rpg/SpriteSheet.png`), this makes it an embedded resource.
- Use `Class#getResource` to load embedded resources, in this case either `getClass().getResource("SpriteSheet.png")` or `getClass().getResource("/rpg/SpriteSheet.png")` to be be sure.
- Use `ImageIO.read` over `ImageIcon`.  It will at least throw an `IOException` when the image can not be loaded for some reason, where as `ImageIcon` can fail silently.
- Make sure that the instance of `GraphicsPanel` which is loading the resources is the same instance that is on the screen

Comment: @ixin I've added this answer as a summary of points I think we covered in our "conversation", could look over them and make sure I've covered the main points. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.
I took your code, and added the panel to a JFrame. Also, I call `getParameters();` before adding the Panel to the JFrame.

```
import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener,
        MouseMotionListener {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GraphicsPanel s = new GraphicsPanel();
        s.getParameters();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(s);       
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int currentTileType = 0;//tile types. 0=bgtile, 1=object, 2=NPC
    public String currentTileName = "";
    public Image currentTile;

    public GraphicsPanel() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(currentTile, 100, 100, this);//Nothing gets drawn here
    }

    public void getParameters() {
        currentTile = new ImageIcon("test.jpg").getImage();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   
}
```

Comment: I am implementing this JPanel extension inside of a class that extends JFrame. I think the issue has to do with my pathname to my file

Comment: Try running your application as Administrator. Also, try putting the image file within your eclipse project and accessing with only the file name.